# Can I use a normal bubble sort to alphabetize a list?

Tags: c++, sorting, alphabetical

I know bubble sort and selection sort sorts numbers but can it also do it with words? Can it alphabetize a list? I've made a selection sort program and bubble sort but do not know how I could change it to work with words. I need to make a program that takes in items with quantities from the user and outputs them in alphabetical order while still maintaining the numbers. I'm not asking for the entire program by any means, just this detailed help. I also know it suggested to use parallel arrays in this. Please and thank you!

```
void selectionSort(int arr[], int length)
{
int lowest = 0;
int temp;

//each time moving the lowest item

for(int i=0; i < length-1; ++i)
{
//goes through array once starting from "boundary"
lowest = i;
for(int j=(i+1); j < length; ++j)
{
  if(arr[j] < arr[lowest])
  {
    lowest = j;
  }
}
//swap 
temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[lowest];
arr[lowest] = temp;
}
}
```

Comment: If you can define a comparison operator for it, any sorting algorithm can sort it. I do recommend using`std::sort` and `std::vector` instead of trying to write all by hand. (And `std::swap`)

Comment: You need to.learn how strings work in C.

Comment: You can sort everything which can be ordered. An "order" means there is a less predicate (e.g. overloaded `operator<`) which fulfills: 1) if a < b then not b < a and 2) if not a < b and not b < a then a == b. Strings can be ordered lexicographically (used in every printed dictionary I know). The standard `operator<` for strings sorts similar (comparing the ASCII values of characters). However, it does not need to be an order which makes sense in real life but these are included, of course. E.g. I once sorted floating point values by their bit patterns what was sufficient for what I needed it.

Comment: You need a tutorial on sorting.

Comment: The reason that you've only seen (and written) implementations that sort numbers is that they make for very simple examples, not that you can't sort anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The code you want to have is:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

void f(std::vector<std::string> &v)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

The vector contains the values and knows how many elements are in use.

The string deals with all stuff related to strings, including the length and the sorting.

The sort has the actual algorithm (or multiple) to sort as efficient as possible, much more efficient than your bubble sort.

If you want something else than the default sorting, you can pass a lambda (or another callable) to the sort function. See the examples on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for more details.

So actually 1 line of code with a minimal chance on bugs. Correct usage of C++ can make it simple to solve trivial problems.